# Repeatedly hide and show the view of another UIViewController

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, popupwindow, swift4.2

I am trying to build something like a Popup-View (in code it's the editLayoutVC). Everything is working well if I want to build and destroy the "editLayoutVC".

But what I need is to repeatedly show and hide the popup without destroying it.

My code snippet so far:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController{
...
    let editLayoutVC: EditLayoutViewController = EditLayoutViewController()
...

// shows the view of editLayoutVC only once, second call
// result in nothing/maybe it does something but the view
// of editLayoutVC will not  show up
func showEditLayout(){ 
        self.addChild(editLayoutVC)
        editLayoutVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(editLayoutVC.view)
        editLayoutVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

// this works repeatedly, but it creates and  
// destroys the editLayoutVC. This is not what i want
func showEditLayout(){ /
let editLayoutVC2 = EditLayoutViewController()
        self.addChild(editLayoutVC2)
        editLayoutVC2.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(editLayoutVC2.view)
        editLayoutVC2.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
...
```

```
class EditLayoutViewController: UIViewController{
...
    func didTapCloseButton(){
        willMove(toParent: nil)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        removeFromParent()
    }
...
```

I think, I am doing something wrong by removing/hidding the view. I also tried a lot with the three function in didTapCloseButton() but it didn't work either.

I think my code would work, when I would use a Storyboard. But I dont want to use Storyboards and trying to solve this programmatically.

I am sure I am missing something trivial. Would be nice, if someone could show me what it is that i miss

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using a viewController rather than a UIView?

Comment: I think it's not so important that it has to be a UIViewController. 
Theoretically the view of the popup window only need to contain a video / text or image - depending on the situation and it should not be destroyed / recreated.